# How to get the directory that a package apt-get installed?

Tags: nvidia, cuda

I am trying to [install](https://medium.com/better-programming/install-tensorflow-1-13-on-ubuntu-18-04-with-gpu-support-239b36d29070) tensorflow-gpu on Ubuntu 18.04.

Here is a step

```
sudo apt-get install libcupti-dev
echo 'export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/cuda/extras/CUPTI/lib64:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH' >> ~/.bashrc
```

It seems that the libcupti-dev to be installed in 
/usr/local/cuda/extras/CUPTI, but I didn't see the directory after "apt-get install libcupti-dev" executed successfully.

Any ideas?

Comment: if it was an Ubuntu package then it installed to /usr, i.e /usr/include, /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu.

Comment: @doug How to determine if it is an Ubuntu package?

Comment: Run `dpkg -L libcupti-dev` to files location. The `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH...` command redefines library management on runtime and is not related to installation with apt/dpkg at all.

Comment: @N0rbert  Thanks a lot! Please move your comments to answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As usual you can use `dpkg -L libcupti-dev` to show files location.
See *dpkg-query actions* section of `man dpkg` locally or [online](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man1/dpkg.1.html).

The export `LD_LIBRARY_PATH...` command redefines library management on runtime and is not related to installation with apt/dpkg at all.